# Detect if attach or detach Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have project and user table, i want to update attached user in project so i want to attach more or remove user to project

My code look like this

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
     $project = Project::find($id);
                $project->update($request->all());
                if ($project->users()->where('users.id',$request->input('user_id'))->count() == 0){
                    $project->users()->attach($request->input('user_id'));
                }

                else if($project->users()->where('users.id',$request->input('user_id'))->count() != 0){
                    $project->users()->detach($request->input('user_id'));
                }
                return response()->json($project);
}
```

This code not work correctly when add else if for detach user that want, so anyone help me to resolve this issue and thanks

Comment: Do you have two routes to attach and detach users? What are the conditions for doing so? Post your form data.

Comment: @Sandeesh i have one route for update, i use resource for this purpose

Comment: I've told you this in your last question. You need to have some condition to either attach the user or detach them. What is the condition? Just say that!

Comment: @Sandeesh, i don't understand

Comment: Join the chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145711/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-44326410-detect-if-attach-or-detach-laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could finally figure out what you need based on the discussion in the chat.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $project = Project::find($id);

    $project->update($request->except('user_id'));

    $project->users()->sync($request->input('user_id'));

    return response()->json($project);
}
```

Comment: @Akram the auth scaffolding is for frontend auth. It won't work for API. You need to use the token guard for the api along with the auth laravel provides. Ideal option would be to go with JWT or OAuth.